# Get user info with name or UserID from Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Can I know what's mistake in here?
I have two tables in my database.
it is this

[image: table]

[image: table2]

I have written the code as search player thing. I'll put the name or userid in the form and it'll process the information of user.

Here is my code

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="" method="post">
 Search: <input type="text" name="term" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 <?php
 include('config.php');
 if (!empty($_REQUEST['term']))
 {
 $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);
 $sql = " select u.* from users u inner join ranks r ON (u.UserID = r.UserID) where u.UserID = '%" . $term . "%'";
 $r_query = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query))
  {
  echo 'Name: ' . $row['Name'];
  echo '<br /> Cash: ' . $row['Cash'];
  echo '<br /> Score: ' . $row['Score'];
  echo '<br /> Race: ' . $row['Race'];
  echo '<br /> Horseshoe: ' . $row['Horseshoe'];
  }
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why % at '%" . $term . "%'?

Comment: And what is the problem/error ?

Comment: Read this before you go any further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs a `$conn` wich contains the database connection, otherwise you'll run into errors

Comment: (1) you are only searching in `UserID` but not in `Name` (2) wildcards (`%`) can only be used with `LIKE` (3) you try to access columns that you never selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should update your `config.php` to `mysqli_` functions. 
and the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli_query()` functions need 2 Parameters.
 First `$conn`, second: the variable 
finally your code should look like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    Search: <input title="searchfield" required type="text" name="term"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php

include('config.php');

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"])) {
    $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST["term"]); //make sure the $conn isset
    $sql = "SELECT u.* FROM users u INNER JOIN ranks r ON (u.UserID = r.UserID) WHERE u.UserID LIKE '%" . $term . "%'"; // change = to LIKE
    $r_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)) {
        echo 'Name: ' . $row['Name'];
        echo '<br /> Cash: ' . $row['Cash'];
        echo '<br /> Score: ' . $row['Score'];
        echo '<br /> Race: ' . $row['Race'];
        echo '<br /> Horseshoe: ' . $row['Horseshoe'];
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

your `config.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "idkw0t";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: <?php
         $connect = mysql_connect("lol.com", "idkw0t", "idkw0t") or die("I can't connect to the server, Please Re-Check the DB info.");
         mysql_select_db("idkw0t") or die ("I can't find the database, Please Re-Check the DB Info."); 
?>
this is my config.php

Comment: then replace `$connect` with `$conn` and all should be fine

Comment: <?php $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("I can't connect to the server, Please Re-Check the DB info."); mysql_select_db("idkw0t") or die ("I can't find the database, Please Re-Check the DB Info."); ?>

Comment: @DevilRooter updated both scripts. try now it should do the trick

Comment: Works only for userid 1. when I type "1" and press submit. I get information of first user but 2,3,4,5,6,7. nothing comes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `like` in query as follows

```
$sql = " select u.* from users u inner join ranks r ON (u.UserID = r.UserID) where u.UserID like '%" . $term . "%'";
```